# Extract JSON Value

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am having some problem when trying to extract value from JSON. Here is the JSON returned from my servlet:

```
[
    {
        "eventDesc":"My sons 5th year birthday party",
        "eventDate":"12/11/2014",
        "eventID":"1",
        "eventName":"Birthday party",
        "eventTime":"17:00",
        "eventX":"41803.2",
        "eventY":"38210.8",
        "eventBy":"Gabriel"
    },
    {
        "eventDesc":"Steamboat Gathering",
        "eventDate":"20/11/2014",
        "eventID":"2",
        "eventName":"Gathering",
        "eventTime":"19:00",
        "eventX":"41551.6",
        "eventY":"38211.7",
        "eventBy":"JunHong"
    }
]
```

And I have no idea how should I extract it record per record because I have to plot each record onto the map.

I have these codes to extract from the JSON returned in servlet:

```
public void getThemesOnMap() throws JSONException{
    String page;
    BufferedReader in;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/MyProject/MyServlet");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        page = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(page);
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(page);
            int length = jsonArray.length();
            for(int i = 1; i < length; i++){
                JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String eventName = attribute.getString("eventName");
                String eventX = attribute.getString("eventX");
                String eventY = attribute.getString("eventY");

                PictureMarkerSymbol graphicIcon;
                graphicIcon = new PictureMarkerSymbol(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.busstopicon));
                Point p = new Point(Double.parseDouble(eventX), Double.parseDouble(eventY));
                Symbol symbol = graphicIcon;

                HashMap<String, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                attrMap.put("eventName", eventName);

                graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(p, symbol, attrMap));
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it does not plot anything onto the map. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

How could I format my JSON to return as:

```
{Events:[
{
    "eventDesc":"My sons 5th year birthday party",
    "eventDate":"12/11/2014",
    "eventID":"1",
    "eventName":"Birthday party",
    "eventTime":"17:00",
    "eventX":"41803.2",
    "eventY":"38210.8",
    "eventBy":"Gabriel"
},
{
    "eventDesc":"Steamboat Gathering",
    "eventDate":"20/11/2014",
    "eventID":"2",
    "eventName":"Gathering",
    "eventTime":"19:00",
    "eventX":"41551.6",
    "eventY":"38211.7",
    "eventBy":"JunHong"
}]
}
```

And this is my servlet method to retrieve the data from database:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(request.getParameter("SQL1")!=null){

    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");

        PreparedStatement statement = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM event");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            JSONObject eventInfo = new JSONObject();
            eventInfo.put("eventID", result.getString("eventID"));
            eventInfo.put("eventName", result.getString("eventName"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDesc", result.getString("eventDesc"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDate", result.getString("eventDate"));
            eventInfo.put("eventTime", result.getString("eventTime"));
            eventInfo.put("eventX", result.getString("eventX"));
            eventInfo.put("eventY", result.getString("eventY"));
            eventInfo.put("eventBy", result.getString("eventBy"));
            jsonArray.put(eventInfo);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    out.println(jsonArray.toString());
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a JSON parser?

Comment: Let me update my question again. Give me 5 minutes :)

Comment: First go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then understand that JSON "objects" map to Java Maps and JSON "arrays" map to Java Lists.  A JSON parser will parse the data into a "nest" of Maps and Lists to match the structure of the original JSON.  (And if you paste your JSON string into an online JSON parser/formatter such as http://json.parser.online.fr/ then it will be displayed in a nicely formatted style that is easier to read.)

Comment: (Note that the above JSON is an "array" containing two "objects".) (You are apparently trying to parse first into an "object", and that's not right.)

Comment: i recommend creating a pojo that mimics the json's structure and then use Gson...too easy

Comment: **NO NO NO!!  DO NOT CREATE "POJOs" UNTIL YOU UNDERSTAND JSON!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't use object mapping because that's not that different from map/list-mapping, which are technically POJOs themselves

Comment: @zapl - Because if you start out using POJOs you never really get to understand JSON.  And, besides, virtually every POJO scheme I've ever seen is more complicated and buggy than the equivalent simple Map/List scheme.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: @HotLicks Excuse me, but how should I fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation for the JSON kit you're using.  There are 2-3 different ones that use JSONObject and JSONArray, so I can't say for sure, but generally you'd take your JSON string and use a method of JSONArray to convert into a JSONArray (perhaps `new JSONArray(myJsonString)`).  Then you'd use methods of JSONArray to extract the JSONObjects contained therein.  But first and foremost, study json.org, and study the documentation for your JSON kit, before you attempt anything more.

Comment: (The first two lines after the `try` statement above are total gibberish.  Toss them out completely and rewrite.)

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry but I got a bit confused. Would you mind to post the solutions which can be implemented into my situation?

Comment: Read the documentation.  Understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("your json string here");
```

And browse it

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    JSONObject o = arr.getJSONObject(i);
     //...
```

More information here : http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONObject.html

**edit**

Do like this :

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(page);
int length = jsonArray.length();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    //...
```

**edit2**

To obtain the desired JSON, do like this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(request.getParameter("SQL1")!=null){

    }

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");

        PreparedStatement statement = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM event");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            JSONObject eventInfo = new JSONObject();
            eventInfo.put("eventID", result.getString("eventID"));
            eventInfo.put("eventName", result.getString("eventName"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDesc", result.getString("eventDesc"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDate", result.getString("eventDate"));
            eventInfo.put("eventTime", result.getString("eventTime"));
            eventInfo.put("eventX", result.getString("eventX"));
            eventInfo.put("eventY", result.getString("eventY"));
            eventInfo.put("eventBy", result.getString("eventBy"));
            jsonArray.put(eventInfo);
        }
        result.put("Events", (Object) jsonArray);
    }

    catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you help me check my updated portion? Because when I try to print out the page in console, it's empty

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. The console is still empty

Comment: And http://localhost:8080/MyProject/MyServlet does give the json string in a browser ?

Comment: Any ideas? I am still stuck

Comment: @IWasSoLost - Your code above doesn't match ToYonos' solution.

Comment: It's not a JSON issue if your page String is empty (if i understand well)

Comment: @ToYonos Could you please help me take a look at my edited portion to format the output of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to map the json you might want to use existing javascript/jquery library or so
but for you to know I'm assuming that you want to create a Timeline Map so here the algorithm:

`you need to loop over dates
 check any event from this date from you json by looping through it
   if there are events then put it to the map horizontally
   then start the next loop to check.`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use the RestTemplate-class of the spring framework ? 
It directly combines the http-request with possibility to map a JSON reply onto a pojo in about 5 lines of code. The advantage is that you know that the mapping is working correctly and the source code is much more readible.

Example that helped me a lot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: Mind to provide me with some example?

Comment: I added a url to my post

Comment: But how do I implement it into my project?